# Hazelcast: number of threads on a cluster with multi CPU machines

Tags: java, multithreading, hazelcast

I made a cluster using Hazelcast: it has one master node that spreads Runnables among 5 other nodes. My question is: does Hazelcast `ExecuterService` perform computations within each computing node also in parallel?

I mean, if each of my computing nodes have 4 CPUs (or 4 cores on a single CPU), what will be the total number of threads participating in computations? 5 (thread per node) or 5*4=20 (thread per CPU/core)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we can figutre it out manually:

```
public class HazelcastTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        IExecutorService exec = instance.getExecutorService("exec");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            exec.submit(new MyRunnable());
        }
    }

}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable, Serializable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.err.println("threadId: " + threadId);
    }

}
```

The result is:

```
threadId: 48
threadId: 48
threadId: 46
threadId: 48
threadId: 46
threadId: 48
threadId: 46
threadId: 46
threadId: 54
threadId: 48
...etc...
```

Another proof is that CPU monitor shows 100% load for all available cores.

Answer (score 1):

your runnable sent to the member will run once per member, which means it will use only single thread. So 5

Comment: Actually, I doubt it. I performed an experiment that showed me 100% of CPU load on each node (each CPU core was fully loaded). So I bet Hazelcast parallelize computation within each machine, I just want some proof.

Comment: Checkout this code snippet: https://gist.github.com/gurbuzali/a87bc828404d9a062267

It shows that only a single thread is used for executing the callable on each node.